# Find specific locations closest to a given position

Tags: python-3.x, google-api, google-places-api

I want to find closest specific location of a place like closest hospital or closest police station or etc to a given position. I saw this code in one of the questions but i don't get any response to this code.

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

google_places = GooglePlaces(API KEY)

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        location='London, England',
        radius=20000, types=[types.TYPE_FOOD])

print (query_result.html_attributions)
```

I want a working code that helps me to find these closest community places like police stations, banks, hospitals to a given position. 
Thanks!

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Do you get any errors? Note from the documentation (https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests) that you can only restrict search results by one specific type and you only get around 60 max results.

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I don't get any output at all. I only get '[]' as an output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code worked for me,

```
from googleplaces import GooglePlaces, types, lang

google_places = GooglePlaces("AIzaSyCNLxPxFmG3kfrALBUkRFb_R5UdemVnqqQ")

query_result = google_places.nearby_search(
        location="51.529972 -0.127676",
        radius=20000, types=[types.TYPE_RESTAURANT])

#if query_result.has_attributions:
print (query_result.places)
```